# error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications when installing npm modules on wsl

Tags: c++, npm, c++17, node-gyp

When performing yarn install on wsl I get the following error:

```
Directory: node_modules/node-hid
Output:
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=18.13.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=linux)
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
gyp info using node@18.13.0 | linux | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at \"/usr/bin/python3\"
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.13.0/node-v18.13.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.13.0/node-v18.13.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.13.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.13.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/home/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/node_modules/node-hid/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/.cache/node-gyp/18.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/.cache/node-gyp/18.13.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/.cache/node-gyp/18.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/node_modules/node-hid',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
make: Entering directory '/home/node_modules/node-hid/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hidapi-linux-hidraw/hidapi/linux/hid.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/hidapi-linux-hidraw.a
  COPY Release/hidapi-linux-hidraw.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/HID-hidraw/src/HID.o
../src/HID.cc:71:5: error: ISO C++17 does not allow dynamic exception specifications
   71 |     throw(JSException);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.5",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^4.0.9",
    "ethers": "^6.0.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.12.6",
    "hardhat-contract-sizer": "^2.7.0",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.23",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.1.1",
    "solhint": "^3.3.8",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.6.1",
    "@chainlink/test-helpers": "^0.0.7-alpha",
    "@chainlink/token": "^1.1.0",
    "@openzeppelin/contracts": "^4.8.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "hardhat-shorthand": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: The module needs to be compiled with `-std=c++14` or lower. It is using a C++ feature that was removed with C++17 and newer compilers will default to the latter.

Comment: That problem line was also deprecated in C++11.  You are building code that was explicitly meant for a C++ standard that is at least 20 years old.

Comment: @user17732522 your comment reinforces my suspicion that the root cause of my problem is that he is not finding a required pre-built node module "node-hid" and thus attempting to compile it himself.